# Dialogflow Beta integration and session ID

Tags: javascript, wordpress, header, dialogflow-es

I hope someone would be able to guide me, I'm a beginner with Dialogflow

I'm integrating Dialogflow on Wordpress by using their 'Dialogflow Beta integration' and i'm wondering what would be the best way to produce a `session-id` for visitors coming on the website:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/dialogflow-console/fast/messenger/bootstrap.js?v=1"></script>
<df-messenger
  intent="WELCOME"
  chat-title="cdcloudlogix-agent"
  agent-id="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  language-code="en"
  session-id="??????"
></df-messenger>
```

I'm integrating this piece of code in the header of the landing page, but I was wondering what would be the best practice to handle this type of situation. Or should I make use of the `user-id` instead?

If you need more information, don't hesitate to ask!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can omit including `session-id` in your code. When `session-id` is not defined, Dialogflow will generate a unique `session-id` for each chat. See [Dialogflow Messenger doc](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations/dialogflow-messenger#html-customize) for reference.

[image]